# Restarting my game does not work as intended

Tags: java

So when you press the *R* the balls that were drawn are erased. However the balls do not do their action afterwards

Here is the method where the action happens. when you press the *R* key `game.restart` is true

```
    //EnitityB
    public void ballTick() {
        y += speed;
        if (game.restart) {
            y = 0;
        }
    }
```

Here is the method that calls ballTick() from above

```
    public void tick() {
        for (int i = 0; i < eB.size(); i++) {
            entityB = eB.get(i);

            entityB.ballTick();
        }
        
    }
```

here is the method that erases everything

```
    public void reTry() {
        if(game.restart == true) {
            eB.clear();    
        }
    }
```

`tick()` is looped elsewhere so it's always happening. so I'm not sure why something like `speed` isn't applied.

Comment: Where's the line that sets game.restart back to false so it doesn't just clear again?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just didn't have it so that `game.restart` is false when you let go of the *R* key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never reset `game.restart` to false. Currently your program will constantly run as you have never told it when to stop running.